# Why is ServiceStack producing an HTML response when I throw my custom exception?

Tags: c#, json, exception, servicestack

In the server side code, I throw a custom exception. I am expecting ServiceStack to wrap the exception in the `ResponseStatus` property and inform the client the appropriate exception.

I can catch a `WebServiceException` in the client code but upon examining the exception, it doesn't show my custom exception, but instead some HTML response and some deserialization errors.

I tested with Google Chrome's REST console and was expecting to get a JSON response, since I specified the request to the JSON endpoint, but the response was still HTML.

How should I throw and catch the custom exception correctly?

---

EDIT: I have found out why it was outputting html; It was because I am using the new async way to write the service.

I tried a simple example *(like the one below)* and it produces the HTML output. How can I fix this?

```
public async Task<SimpleResponse> Any(SimpleRequest simpleRequest)
{
    throw new CustomException("Force throw exception!");
}
```

Comment: from which class are you applying the inheritance?

Comment: what inheritance are you implying? the above method is defined in a class that is inherited from ServiceStack.Service class

Comment: sorry, I meant for the customException class

Comment: That is an exception that derives from Exception class. I just tried using just a normal .Net Exception and it still responded in the html page...